# Почему в Delphi (Sender as TObject) выдает ошибку?

Tags: delphi, объекты

```
If N290.Checked then
begin
  (Sender as TSpeedButton).Flat := False;
end;
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Invalid typecast (Неверное преобразование типов)

Ко всем кнопкам TSpeedButton на панельке инструментов привязано одно контекстное меню. Нужно перехватывать кнопку, на которой контекстное меню было вызвано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ошибка в строке с "Sender as TSpeedButton", это значит, что Sender НЕ является экземпляром класса TSpeedButton или его наследника. *Предположу*, что Sender это объект типа MenuItem или Action. Во-первых, надо достоверное выяснить тип объекта в отладчике. Во-вторых почитать справку по этому классу, что там из него можно извлечь.

Comment: Спасибо! Не обратил внимание, что _прописывал код в функции_, где Sender имеет другой тип... **Проблема решена**.